# Firefox Binary OK for Manual Run but Fails When Scheduled

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG in which the firefox binary path is specified:

```
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = "/usr/bin/firefox"
```

It executes consistently for manual runs (`airflow dags test <dag>`) but every scheduled run fails with the following message:

`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable`

If I don't specify the firefox binary, the manual runs fail as well.

Points of clarification:

1. Firefox has been installed by SNAP, and I do the following to work around the profile:

```
# To address an issue caused by the Snap installation of Firefox
tmp_dir = os.path.join(home_directory, 'tmp')
os.environ['TMPDIR'] = tmp_dir
```

2. `/etc/systemd/system/airflow-scheduler.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="PATH=/home/lars/.local/bin:/usr/bin/firefox"
EnvironmentFile=/home/lars/.local/bin/airflow
User=lars
Group=lars
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/lars/.local/bin/airflow scheduler
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```